# Laravel 5 can't store image name in database

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.1, image-upload

I am using Laravel 5.1

I can move image to my destination folder with correct name but in database it's saved with a temp name, like `D:\xampp\tmp\phpC7EA.tmp`

**form.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('image', 'Upload Image', ['class'=>'control-label col-sm-4']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        {!! Form::file('image', null) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**TeacherController.php**

```
public function store(TeacherRequest $request)
{
    Teacher::create($request->all());
    $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('image')->move(base_path().'/public/images', $image_name);
    Session::flash('success_message', 'Teacher has been added successfully!');
    return redirect('teacher');
}
```

Comment: you will have to reset the value of the image path in teacher table after moving image into destination folder and I would recommend that if the uploaded image contains some confidential information then you should move it in storage directory for security purpose like this way `$request->file('image')->move(storage_path().'/public/images', $image_name);`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i know it need to be reset. but how i can do that?

Comment: `$teacher = Teacher::create($request->all()); $teacher->image=newpath; $teacher->save();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem when updating the record with new image,image name save in correct name but tmp name in database like `'C:\wamp\tmp\phpD10D.tmp'`
what i did before saving is

```
$request['img'] = $imageName; //with new name
$images->update($request->all());
```

I know it should be like `$_FILE['img']['name'] = $imageName`

but how to manage it in Laravel 5.1